# Table columns not correctly separated

Tags: tables

The following code produces a table. On the right half (frogs) the columns are not correctly distributed as on the left half (birds). How to make it work correctly?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}   
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c| c|c| c|c| c|c |c}
\multirow{2}{*}{AAA} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{birds} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{frogs} \\ \cline{2-9}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{w/o huge hat} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{w/ huge hat} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{w/o huge hat} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{w/ huge hat} \\
\hline
$\frac{1}{3}$ & 2.75 & 3.6 & 2.75 & 3.68 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ \hline
1 & 8.3 & 10 & 8.2 & 10 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 \\ \hline
3 & 24.25 & 28 & 24.25 & 28.5 & 44 & 48 & 45 & 45 \\ \hline\hline
$\frac{p}{q}$ & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to [@Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541988/5001), but omitting all vertical lines and using fewer but well-spaced horizontal lines in order to create a more open "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}  
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c *{8}{C} @{}}
AAA & \multicolumn{4}{c}{birds} & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{frogs} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{w/o huge hat} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{w/ huge hat} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{w/o huge hat} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{w/ huge hat} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9} 
$1/3$ & 2.75 & 3.6 & 2.75 & 3.68 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
1 & 8.3 & 10 & 8.2 & 10 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 \\ 
3 & 24.25 & 28 & 24.25 & 28.5 & 44 & 48 & 45 & 45 \\ 
\midrule
$p/q$ & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ 
   & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ \\ 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to add a vertical line after the 'AAA' column while not extending to the 'p/q' row?

Comment: @xiaohuamao - Short answer: No. Longer answer: The whole point of not using any vertical lines and using fewer, but well spaced horizontal lines is to give the table an open and inviting look. If, however, you prefer a closed "look", then this solution is definitely not the right one for you.

Comment: @xiaohuamao - Even longer answer: If the purpose of the vertical bar between the first and second column is *not* to reintroduce a closed look but just to provide a bit more visual separation between the header column and the 8 data columns, then no vertical bar is needed. Instead, just replace `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c *{8}{C} @{}}` in the answer shown above with, say, `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c @{\qquad} *{8}{C} @{}}`. Give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

The width of the multi column cell with`w/o huge hat` is bigger than sum of widths of the spanned columns. To have equal width that columns you need to define their widths (for example as `p{<width>}`) or simpler use `tabularx` with all columns with equal widths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{C|C| C|C| C|C| C|C |C}
\multirow{2}{*}{AAA} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{birds} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{frogs} \\ \cline{2-9}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{w/o huge hat} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{w/ huge hat} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{w/o huge hat} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{w/ huge hat} \\
\hline
$\frac{1}{3}$ & 2.75 & 3.6 & 2.75 & 3.68 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ \hline
1 & 8.3 & 10 & 8.2 & 10 & 15 & 15 & 15 & 15 \\ \hline
3 & 24.25 & 28 & 24.25 & 28.5 & 44 & 48 & 45 & 45 \\ \hline\hline
$\frac{p}{q}$ & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ & $\frac{31}{97}$ & $\frac{53}{157}$ \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]